# Not able to execute the commands in same sudo session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Not able to execute below touch command in same session of user - weblogic. Instead below touch command is executing on user - djaiswa2 and is failing [Because it is trying to access the path whose owner is weblogic].

```
[djaiswa2@cdcesb01 tmp]$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo su - weblogic;

touch /opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys;
chmod 755 /opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys;

[djaiswa2@cdcesb01 tmp]$ sh -x test.sh
+ sudo su - weblogic
Last login: Thu Aug 26 00:38:06 EDT 2021 on pts/0

-bash-4.2$ exit
logout
+ touch /opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys
touch: cannot touch ‘/opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys’: Permission denied
+ chmod 755 /opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod: cannot access ‘/opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: When you put multiple commands in a script, the second one doesn't start until the first one exited; so _of course_ `touch` won't run until `sudo su` exits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `su` command with `-c` option to specify the commands to be executed.

for exampe:

```bash
sudo su - weblogic -c "touch /opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod +x /opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Comment: Asking password, if use suggestion. Whereas simply using sudo is not asking it. '[djaiswa2@cdcesb01 ~]$ sudo su - weblogic -c "touch /opt/middleware/test.txt; chmod 755 /opt/middleware/test.txt"
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
[sudo] password for djaiswa2:
[djaiswa2@cdcqa1esb03 ~]$ sudo su - weblogic
Last login: Thu Aug 26 14:27:42 EDT 2021 from 10.13.217.115 on pts/0'

Comment: Can you please check that if you can here?

Comment: Thanks. But asking password, if i am using your suggestion.

 Simply using sudo is not asking it. 
 ```
 [drter2@cdadc01 ~]$ sudo su - weblogic -c "touch /opt/middleware/test.txt; chmod 755 /opt/middleware/test.txt" 
 We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things: #1) Respect the privacy of others. #2) Think before you type. #3) With great power comes great responsibility. [sudo] password for drter2: 
 
 [drter2@cdadc01 ~]$ sudo su - weblogic Last login: Thu Aug 26 14:27:42 EDT 2021 from 10.13.217.115
 ```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and therein the bullet point regarding questions "that have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @Eagertolearn, ...as to making sudo passwordless, that's a question of the contents of your sudoers file. Generally, you should have a separate `NOPASSWD:` entry in there for each individual command you want to allow to be run without a password, specifying the individual user authorized to run the script that invokes that command.

Comment: @Eagertolearn, ...I'd also urge you not to copy the `sudo su -` antipattern -- yes, it's all over, but it's a horrible practice. `sudo` itself can do everything `su` can, so there's never a need to combine them; `sudo -i` gives you an interactive shell, but _in a script_ you should be using `sudo -u weblogic touch /opt/middleware/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `sudo -u weblogic chmod +x ...` so that your `/etc/sudoers` entries are only giving access to run those _specific_ touch and chmod commands as the `weblogic` user from _one specific_ source user.